# Jquery mouse over event

Tags: php, jquery

I want to show a hidden `div` when I mouse over a link on my table cell. The event only fires up on the first row. This is what i did:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show_div").mouseover(function() { 
        $("#hello").css('visibility', 'visible'); 
    });
    $("#hello").mouseover(function() { 
        $("#hello").css('visibility', 'visible'); 
    });
    $("#hello").mouseout(function() { 
        $("#hello").css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <div id="bulkOptionContainer" class="col-xs-4">
            <select class="form-control" name="bulk_options" id="">
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <option value="publish">Publish</option>
                <option value="draft">Draft</option>
                <option value="delete">Delete</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Apply"/>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="posts.php?source=add_post">Add New</a>
        </div>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="selectAllCheckBoxes"></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Tags</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $query = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY post_id DESC";
        $result_set = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        confirm_query($result_set);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)):?>

            <tr>
                <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxes" name="checkBoxArray[]"
                                  value="<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>"></label></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['post_id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['post_author'] ?></td>
                <td width="100%">

                    <!-- link to over-->
                    <a id="show_div"
                       href="../post.php?p_id=<?php echo $row['post_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['post_title'] ?></a>
                     <!-- div to become visible on hover-->
                    <div id="hello" style="visibility:hidden;">
                        <p>post</p>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo sel_cat_byId($row['post_category_id']) ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['post_status'] ?></td>
                <td><img width="100" class="img-responsive" src="../images/<?php echo $row['post_image'] ?>"></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['post_tag'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['post_comment_count']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['post_date'] ?></td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="posts.php?delete=<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?> "
                       onclick="alert('Are You Sure?')">Delete</a></td>
                </td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="posts.php?source=edit_post&edit=<?php echo $row['post_id']; ?>">Edit</a>
                </td>
                </td>

            </tr>



        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

****the event only fires up on the first row.
Thanks

Comment: Use class instead of ID. ID's should be unique

Comment: Please include an [mcve] in your question. That is: This is a problem with your jQuery, so post the relevant part of the generated html. Even better: Boil that html down to the bare essentials needed to reproduce the problem. That would make it a lot easier for you to see what is wrong with the code too.

Comment: You have a couple of issues - firstly your PHP loop will create many elements with the same `id`, which is invalid as they should be unique. Secondly your HTML is invalid as a `div` element cannot be a child of a `table`.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII It works finebut its selecting every link and the mouseout no longer working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace your id  with class and then try this

```js
$(".show_div").mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).next(".hello").css('visibility', 'visible'); 
    });
    $(".show_div").mouseout(function() { 
        $(this).next(".hello").css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="show_div"
                       href="#">abc</a>
                     <!-- div to become visible on hover-->
                    <div class="hello" style="visibility:hidden;">
                        <p>post</p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: it's select next element. Like here it's select next element whose class is "hello".